# FOF_NORECURSION while deleting a file with subfolders

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, recycle-bin

Can someone explain to me what does the MSDN description of [`FOF_NORECURSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shfileopstructa) flag mean:

> FOF_NORECURSION
>
> Only perform the operation in the local directory. Do not operate
>   recursively into subdirectories, which is the default behavior.

when used with `SHFileOperation` function to delete a folder?

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sfos = {0};
sfos.hwnd = hWnd;
sfos.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
sfos.pFrom = folderPath;   //Must be doubly-null-terminated
sfos.pTo = NULL;
sfos.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | 
              FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NORECURSION;

SHFileOperation(&sfos);
```

My understanding was that if I'm calling it on a folder that contains sub-folders that folder will not get deleted. But that's not what I see.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `FOF_FILESONLY` flag to not recurse into subfolders.  And to explicitly quality the deletion operation on `*.*` with your path.

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(nullptr);

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT sfos = { 0 };
    sfos.hwnd = nullptr;
    sfos.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    sfos.pFrom = L"C:\\vacation\\pictures\\*.*\0";
    sfos.pTo = NULL;
    sfos.fFlags = FOF_FILESONLY;

    auto result = SHFileOperation(&sfos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but `pFrom`must be double-null terminated and more correct use `*` instead `*.*` mask. so something like `L"C:\\vacation\\pictures\\*\0";`